# Error while destroying session in PHP

Tags: php, session

I am having problem in session handling in PHP(version 5.2.10). I am using the below mentioned functions for login, logout and validating sessions.

```
login()
{
    session_set_cookie_params(0);
    session_start();
    session_regenerate_id(true);
    $_SESSION['user_id']
}

validate_session()
{
    session_set_cookie_params(0);
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']) === FALSE) {
        session_destroy();
        logout();
        header("Location: login_page");
    }
}

logout()
{
    session_set_cookie_params(0);
    session_start();
    $_SESSION = array();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 3600, '/');
    session_destroy();
}
```

Every page first makes a call to validate_session() function. If session invalid it redirects to the login page. login() function is used for creating the session for the user.
When user clicks logout, the logout() function is called to destroy the session.

The problem is: randomly the logout() function throws the warning:
**Warning: session_destroy(): Session object destruction failed**

I am getting this warning very infrequently. Like out of 20-30 calls to logout, I get it once. Any thoughts?

I am developing on a windows xp machine.

Update: The sessions are stored in file-system.
Path: C:\WINDOWS\Temp

Comment: It seems it's been a long time since you've accepted any answer on stackoverflow...

Comment: Yeah! I have not been very active in stackoverflow. And in some of the cases I haven't got a satisfactory answer yet.

Comment: Hi Varun, Can you explain why you use the trip equals in that comparison? Usually if(!isset()) would be enough, I know it is more ironclad but isset() should only ever return a boolean, Do you really need to validate its type? It is probably not likely, but maybe that is occasionally returning true when it shouldn't?

Comment: Suggestion Add `debug_print_backtrace()` to the logout function, and keep track of the output then compare the outputs, if there a difference, its likely the different call path that's producing your error. (see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-print-backtrace.php)

Comment: Thanks everyone for your suggestions.I am not able to reproduce this (I am using the same code as earlier). In fact its long since I saw this error. Now I have no idea what was causing this.

Answer (score 2):

Is logout() called elsewhere than in validate_session() ? If not, the problem might be the call to session_destroy() before logout()

You could try this:

```
validate_session()
{
    session_set_cookie_params(0);
    session_start();
    if ( !isset( $_SESSION['user_id'] ) ) {
        logout();
        header("Location: login_page");
    }
}

logout()
{
    $_SESSION = array();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 3600, '/');
    session_destroy();
}
```

Comment: This is my preferred solution too, adding the session_destroy to the logout function rather than validate_session() function makes logical sense. One of the advantages this solution provides is preventing a new session from being created on the logout page, which will negate the need for duplicating the session_destroy() functions.

Answer (score 0):

How are you storing your sessions? If it is file based it may be a timeout or permissions error?

Also, i wonder if the regenerate_id is causing the destroy function to look for  a session that isn't technically there anymore. Have you tried setting that boolean argument to false in the regenerate function?

We had this issue on a CakePHP app, but we corrected it by jiggering with the Cake settings.

Comment: session are stored in the file system. I also tried what you suggested but still got this error once. As I mentioned, the error occurs very infrequently (sometimes once in a day), its very difficult for me to make some change and then see if it has fixed the problem.

Comment: Another question, is the user actually logged out when the warning shows up? Or more to the point, aside from the warning, is everything else functioning? If so, you might consider suppressing the warning until you have it figured - that is, if this is a production environment.

Answer (score 0):

Found [something](http://webomania.wordpress.com/2006/11/14/fixing-session-object-destruction-failed-error/) which might be useful on this topic. The basic concerns are:

1. Whether the session is valid to begin with -- what is the return value from `session_start()`?
2. Whether the session files exist in the PHP.ini `session.save_path` and can be deleted.

I suspect in your case it is the first one. I don't remember where but I think I've seen the case where the session invalidated itself and then tried to repeat the process for some reason.